# Spacy 3.06 NLP Named Entity lower case issue

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy-3

I'm trying to determine the named entity from lower case and merge those entities based upon Entity Type i.e "GPE"[image: Output image below here] but spacy is not identifying the entities n lower case e.g "new york".

Example Sentence: "You can hear the musicality in his voice. Some combination of leftover italian rhythms and a new york inflected North Jersey accent."

Answer (score 0):

1. The spaCy models are not perfect, and because of the way NLP models work it's hard to explain individual predictions. If you want strict control for specific cases use a word list.
2. In 3.0, the models were accidentally trained without case augmentation, so they are more sensitive to case variation than they should be (and will have a harder time with stuff like `new york` than they should). This was fixed in 3.1, so if you upgrade (and download the new model) that should help.